# Loss of locale characters in Connections due to use of updateActivityNode method of IBM SBT

Tags: javascript, xpages, ibm-sbt

Hello XPages programmers!

During a work on Xpages application using Connections SBT API I encountered following situation:

Using introduced managed-beans I succesfully connected to Connections and then used activityService object to get specific activityNode.
Problem is, when I use updateActivityNode method of the activityService, data of node stored in Connections loses its locale characters (f.e. ą,ę,ź). It happens even without any changes in activityNode object, calling updateActivityNode method is enough. Data received from Connections seems to be have correct characters thou.

What could be cause of this problem?

Any help will be appreciated!

I use SBT in JS, Tested on Connections 3 and 5, developed using Domino Designer 9

Comment: I think there is an open issue on github, but I can't be sure it's the issue you have.  https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue++

Comment: I read all open issues and unfortunately I found nothing similar to this behavior. I still hope it's just a minor error..

Comment: This can be a bad encoding of the content of the POST. Can you verify , using something like Fiddler or Wireshark, that the encoding is correct (I bet it should be UTF-8), and the content is encoded properly? It might also be due to a bad JSON serialization.

Comment: In addition to Phil, check what encoding your Domino HTTP server is using (In Internet sites or server settings document depending on your config). Activities are based on standard Atom XMLs and it should be using utf-8.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to sniff packets using Wireshark, but it seems these seems to be protected by SSL..
Domino HTTP is set to work with UTF-8 standard. I set manual UTF-8 encoding on my xsp and library as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was so simple that it's embarrassing even to explain it.
After updating SBT from 1.0.0 to 1.0.3 everything works fine. 
Unicode character support in the Java API was added in 20140527 version.

Thanks for your suggestions!